# how to calculate datedifference in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angular js and trying to display a text ie 'recent' if the order was placed within 5 days ago from today. So if the difference in days between todaysDate and the Order.dateCreated <= 5 then I want to display 'recent' otherwise blank:

```
orderid | dateCreated | status
1       | 27-2-2014   | recent
2       | 27-1-2014   |
```

angular script fragment:

```
<table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="order in orders" >
        <td>{{order.id}}</td>
        <td>{{order.dateCreated}}</td>
        <td><span ng-show="(getDate()-order.dateCreated)<=5">recent</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do this in standard JavaScript and expose a method to your scope to allow the orders to use:

Something like this, however, if your dates are currently stored in a UK format as they appear to be in your question. You will not be able to parse them like this, consider having your server-side code spit out a standard format that JavaScript can parse.

If you find you are having problems doing that, cannot change the server-side response from that format, or want to keep the format, you could use a library to parse it, such as: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ This also has some decent tools for checking the difference: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

```
$scope.isRecentOrder = function(date) {

    // Assuming date is a string of parsable format: ie. "2014-01-27T01:00:00+00:00"
    var diff = new Date() - new Date(date);

    // Calculate from milliseconds
    var days = ((((diff / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24);

    return days >= 5;
}
```

Then you can use the directive `ng-show="isRecentOrder(order.dateCreated)"`